# How to render QQuickItem children?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Suppose I have this class:

```
class CustomRow : public QQuickPaintedItem {
    Q_OBJECT

    CustomRow(QQuickItem* parent) {...}
    void paint(QPainter* painter) {
        /* Custom painting of children here */
    }
}
```

How could I position and paint the children in a cusom way? For instance, if I had a `percentLeft` property, how could I make it so that two children are rendered so that the left takes up `percentLeft` of the space there? Suppose it was in QML like this:

```
CustomRow {
    percentLeft: 80
    Text {
        text: "Hi"
    }
    Text {
        text: "Bye"
    }
}
```

How would I make it so that the text that says "Hi" took up 80% of the width of the `CustomRow` item? Do I just need to position the children and they take care of it themselves?

Comment: the parent should not paint the childrens, what is your goal ?, you could place an image of what you want to obtain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I just need to position the children and they take care of it
>   themselves?

Nailed it. Items are responsible for their own painting. You need not concern yourself with that, only with any custom painting that you do.

You can use property bindings to position the children inside the parent item.

Comment: Awesome. What API calls am I looking for? Still pretty new to the whole Qt scene.

Comment: You are asking questions that you shouldn't be asking. Just spend the few hours needed to get familiar with the 101s of the language. It will save you a lot of time compared to asking a question about each and every baby step and waiting for an answer.